# how to do a select from a last result of select

Tags: sql

I want to know if it's  possible to execute query using last query result?

Example 1:

```
select * 
from persons 
where state='CA'
```

Example 2:

```
select * 
from persons 
where age> 18
```

but we  have to use the result of 1.

I do not want to do an `AND (STATE = 'CA' AND AGE > 18)` subquery

Comment: What is wrong with `SELECT * FROM persons WHERE state = 'CA' AND age > 18`?

Comment: `AND (STATE = 'CA' AND AGE > 18)` is not a sub-query, it's an additional WHERE condition. Why don't you want to add that? It seems the natural choice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
-- subquery
select * from (select * from persons where state='CA') where age>18;

-- named-subquery
with ca as (select * from persons where state='CA') select * from ca where age>18;

-- Compound AND
select * from persons where (age>18 and state='CA');

-- Save query results into a table to use later (will not update if persons updates)
create table ca select * from persons where state='CA';

select * from ca where age>18;

-- Save query into a view to use later (will update if persons updates)
create view ca as select * from persons where state='CA';

select * from ca where age>18;
```

These are pretty much your options

Comment: First select is  First  work session  , Select  2  is another session, why we have to search state='CA'. We did it already in 1?

Comment: Updated my edit to include persistent query options (ones that can be saved to the database)

Comment: create view is the most  appropriate solution I believe.

Comment: If this answered your question be sure to mark it as such.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this

```
 select * from persons where state='CA' AND age> 18
```

Comment: "I do not want to do an ```AND (STATE = 'CA' AND AGE > 18)``` subquery". I don't know why, but it's not an option for him.

Comment: so if you need sub query 
```select * from (select * from persons where state='CA') where age>18;```

Comment: @MichaelBianconi well to be fair, his question is how to do subqueries, not finding ways around it

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CTE:

```
with ca as (
      select * 
      from persons 
      where state = 'CA'
     )
select * 
from ca 
where age > 18  ;
```

Or use a temporary table.  The syntax varies by database, but something like this:

```
create temporary table ca as
    select * 
    from persons 
    where state = 'CA';

select * 
from ca 
where age > 18;
```